# Triggering a Smart TV to turn on via a Tornado Warning signal

Tags: television, severe-weather

I live in Oklahoma and we obviously have problems with severe thunderstorms and tornados.

I've been upgrading some stuff around the house to be compatible with Alexa and also recently got a weather alert radio by Midland:

[image]

I had an idea that a smart TV might be mounted on the wall, and in the case of a Tornado Warning, the TV would automatically turn on and navigate to a website showing the latest weather map radar data.

I don't see any way to interface the actual weather alert radio shown above with Alexa or the TV itself, thus I think potentially an Alexa skill might need to be created for this.

Does anyone else have any ideas how something like this might be accomplished? Any suggestions or ever heard of someone else doing something similar?

Comment: I thought that with a tornado warning you only had time to get to a safe place, not to be watching TV.  Think this be better for one of the software/hardware(electronics/PC) sites on here.

Comment: @crip659 That is a good point! Although you can have tornado warnings for counties nearby that you wouldn't need to immediately seek shelter for

Comment: Here is some reading for you, where the TV does it already https://www.reddit.com/r/fireTV/comments/ly8s4h/50_insignia_fire_tv_turned_itself_on_at_4am_to/

Comment: This site is more about fixing houses.  What you will need is something like the super user site or similar.   https://superuser.com/ If not that site they can point you to the right site.  The sites are joined so just have to click the join button.

Comment: This would also likely be a good fit at [iot.se].

Comment: I don't understand why you want the TV to come on.  A weather radio can be set to come on automatically in the event of a local tornado warning.

Comment: @aparente001 The weather map data would just be additional context to understand the storm's size, direction & location

Comment: Won't the weather radio tell you the relative force, direction, current location and expected locationi?

Comment: @aparente001 Yes, radio tells you that information too. However, if you don't know the landmarks/roadways they are referring to then it is not as useful as a radar map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some additional hardware, this should be possible and relatively easy. You could use a Raspberry PI with a receiver for the NOAA weather radio.

There seem to be [some libraries](https://github.com/ke4roh/RPiNWR) out there which allow decoding those transmissions.
A Raspberry PI is also able to turn on a TV via HDMI CEC as long as the TV supports it (most do, may need to be turned on in settings). The PI would also be able to display a website quite easily. Now you just need a very basic script (there may be some no-code ways to do this as well) to monitor the transmissions, send a TV on signal of a warning is received, and refresh the corresponding website.

Answer (score -1):

Not answering your question, because the are other simpler ways to get alerted. Lets start with basic.

You phone is almost always on you, and the first to alert you.

The TV might be in another room, or you might be on the road.

Using the existing Wireless Emergency Alerts (WEA) system you can receive messages alerting you to potential weather warnings for your area.

HERE IS SETTING ON MY ANDROID PHONE

[image]

Once you have an Alert, you can walk (or run) to the TV and tell Alexa to go to Weather channel.

To access this, go to your phone settings.